# Very slow AWS EC2 machine after replacing its root volume

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a production machine (c4.2xlarge) that works fine.
But, when I do the following:

1. Take a snapshot of root volume while the machine is running (I know,
   it is recommended not to do so, but this works fine for me)
2. Create a volume from the snapshot
3. Attach the newly created volume to a pre-production machine (c4.xlarge) as root device (/dev/sda1)
4. Start the pre-production machine

The newly started machine responds **very slowly** initially. As I keep working on the machine, speed starts improving, until after some hours it is as responsive as it was before I replaced its root volume.

Why is this happening?

Intuitively this would seem a *caching* issue, as if the machine needs "warming up" before it performs as expected. But this does not make really sense to me, since all I am doing is replacing the root volume of the machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EBS snapshots are stored on S3. When you create a new EBS volume from a snapshot the data is streamed from S3 to EBS as the blocks are required. I suspect it may also bring down the whole volume, but it can take some time, which is why it prioritizes blocks you need *right now*.

To fix this you pre-warm your volume. The [full procedure is here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html), but I'll outline the key points in this post

1. Use the lsblk command to list the block devices on your instance. Find the new device (in bold here)

.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
**xvdf**  202:80   0  30G  0 disk
xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 disk /
```

1. Use the dd or fio utilities to read all of the blocks on the device.

.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo dd if=/dev/**xvdf** of=/dev/null bs=1M
```

Note that new EBS volumes *do not* need pre-warming, as nothing is stored on S3.

NB: extraneous dots are required to get the formatting to work properly.

Comment: This is 100% correct, @Tim. For a visual display of progress and speeds, `sudo apt-get install pv` (very useful tool) and then `sudo pv -pterab /dev/xvda1 > /dev/null`.  Shows a spiffy progress bar, ETA, percent complete.  Run it again after it's finished and you'll see a dramatic difference that is too consistent to be cache related.  I did this yesterday on a t2.nano, ~5 MiB/s on first pass, ~61 MiB/s after warmup.  This is safe to do with the volume mounted.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info @Michael-sqlbot - I sometimes do get these answer things right! I passed architect pro today as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the caching of disk contents in RAM. As your server runs, things from its filesystem are cached in RAM, allowing those blocks to be retrieved at RAM speeds instead of waiting for the block to be read from disk.

When you start up a new server, nothing is cached on boot, but the cache is populated as load is applied, thereby increasing performance.